# Substitute formal arguments in a function factory r

Tags: r, metaprogramming

I'm trying to make a function factory to make functions with custom formal argument names. The idea is to supply a string to the factory, which in turn substitutes it both in the formals and in the body of the function returned. I've managed to do it using eval(parse(text=paste())) , but I read elsewhere that this bad practice. How can I get the same output while avoiding doing evalparse?

```
MyLinearRateFunctions<-function(varX){

  eval(parse(text=paste("function(a,b,",
                    varX,
                    ") 1/(a + b*",
                    varX,
                    ")",sep="")
  ))

 }

(LinearRateMPG<-MyLinearRateFunctions('mpg'))

# function(a,b,mpg) 1/(a + b*mpg)
# <environment: 0x11c2f2a00>

(LinearRateCYL<-MyLinearRateFunctions('cyl'))

# function(a,b,cyl) 1/(a + b*cyl)
# <environment: 0x11e4cb908>

(LinearRateDISP<-MyLinearRateFunctions('disp'))

# function(a,b,disp) 1/(a + b*disp)
# <environment: 0x11e47eae8>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a more succinct way to get there, but here's one idea:

```
fn <- function(x) {
    f <- eval(bquote(function(a, b) 1 / (a + b * .(as.name(x)))))
    formals(f) <- c(formals(f), setNames(alist(dummy = ), x))
    f
}
```

In the first line of `fn()`, we use `bquote()` to substitute `x` into the math expression.  We need to evaluate that (with `eval()`) to turn it from a call into a function.  Then in the second line, we add the third argument to the formal argument list.  The final line returns the function.

```
fn("mpg")
# function (a, b, mpg) 
# 1/(a + b * mpg)
# <environment: 0x4f05c78>

fn("cyl")
# function (a, b, cyl) 
# 1/(a + b * cyl)
# <environment: 0x4f9ba28>
```

Quick check:

```
fn("mpg")(1, 2, 3)
# [1] 0.1428571
1 / (1 + 2 * 3)
# [1] 0.1428571
```

And THANK YOU for asking for a better alternative to `eval(parse(text = ...))`, it definitely *is* bad practice.

Comment: The function environment can be changed in `eval()`, if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative which uses `pryr::make_function`. This has the added benefit of setting the function "environment" to the  calling environment of the "function factory" call

```
fn2 <- function(x) {
  fbody <- bquote(1 / (a + b * .(as.name(x))))
  fargs <- setNames(alist(,,),c('a','b',x))
  pryr::make_function(fargs,fbody, env=parent.frame(2))
}
```

While this looks like it avoids a call to `eval`, it is simply hidden within `make_function`

Answer (score 1):

This uses only base R and no `eval`.  First set up a function to use as a template and then change the formals, set up the body and set the environment.

```
factory <- function(x, envir = parent.frame()) {
  fun <- function(a, b, x) {}
  names(formals(fun))[[3]] <- x
  body(fun) <- substitute(1/(a+b*x), list(x = as.name(x)))
  environment(fun) <- envir
  fun
}

# test
myfun <- factory("m")
```

giving:

```
> myfun
function (a, b, m) 
1/(a + b * m)
```